# io_service, why and how is it used?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Trying to learn asio, and I'm following the examples from the website.

Why is io_service needed and what does it do exactly? Why do I need to send it to almost every other functions while performing asynchronous operations, why can't it "create" itself after the first "binding".

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Asio's `io_service` is the facilitator for operating on asynchronous functions. Once an async operation is ready, it uses one of `io_service`'s running threads to call you back. If no such thread exists it uses its own internal thread to call you.

Think of it as a queue containing operations. It guarantees you that those operations, when run, will only do so on the threads that called its `run()` or `run_once()` methods, or when dealing with sockets and async IO, its internal thread.

The reason you must pass it to everyone is basically that someone has to wait for async operations to be ready, and as stated in its own documentation `io_service` is ASIO's link to the Operating System's I/O service so it abstracts away the platform's own async notifiers, such as `kqueue`, `/dev/pool/`, `epoll`, and the methods to operate on those, such as `select()`.

Primarily I end up using io_service to demultiplex callbacks from several parts of the system, and make sure they operate on the same thread, eliminating the need for explicit locking, since the operations are serialized. It is a very powerful idiom for asynchronous applications.

You can take a look at the [core documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/basics.html) to get a better feeling of why `io_service` is needed and what it does.

Comment: `Primarily I end up using io_service to demultiplex callbacks from several parts of the system, and make sure they operate on the same thread,(...)` Could you please elaborate a little bit on this idiom?

Comment: @ΔλЛ you just post operations to io_service and when times comes for them to run, it will pick the right thread and run it, maybe serialised if you use a strand to wrap the operations.

Comment: @Berkus makes a good point. The io_service doesn't provide the serialization of callbacks. The strand does